# Globally change value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following "problem". I have a MySQL db, which already has around 200k records. In one of the columns I have a number (decimal). What I would like to do now is to globally add particular value to all the values in that column.

For example if there was 1000, I would like to change it to lets say 1005, then 1002 would change to 1007 etc. etc.

One way would obviously be downloading the whole db, open it in excel, do it there, save back to cvs and upload a new db, but this would be quite time consuming and maybe overcomplicated, so I thought if there was a way of doing this just using some sql command directly in phpBB.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE myTABLE SET columnName=columnName+5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can easily do that in a single `Update` statement:

```
Update table_name Set column_name = column_name + 5;
```